# A Level Mathematics - Probability

Tags: probability

> Each of $n$ players, where $n > 2$, tosses a fair coin. If **the result of any player's toss is different from that of all the remaining players**, then that player wins the game. Otherwise, all the players toss again until one player wins.
>
> What is the probability of any player wins the game in a number of rounds $r$?

I don't quite understand the questions (bold part). Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: The situation is symmetric, yes?  So the answer is just $\frac 1n$, unless I am missing something.  I am assuming that "success" refers to your chances of winning the game.

Comment: It basically means that if everyone gets a heads except 1 person who gets a tails, or vice versa, then that person wins or vice versa

Comment: @lulu It could however also be the probability that we have a winner.

Comment: Please clarify which probability you mean : The probability that anyone wins the game in the next round ? The probability that you win the game ? Or , finally , the probability you win in the next round ?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  As you can see from the comments, people are not sure what you are asking.

Comment: If your question still is merely for clarification on the bold section, here is an example scenario.  Players A,B,C,D are all playing the game.  In the first turn, everyone flips.  A got heads, B got heads, C got tails, and D got tails.  Since there was not a unique person who got a result all on their own, all players toss again.  This next turn maybe A got heads, B got heads, C got heads and D got tails.  Now we see that D was the only person who got tails.  Since D got a result that was different than all other players, D is declared the winner.

Comment: Now, going on to discussing the probability problem itself... we should clarify terminology here.  The "*game*" is the overall activity being performed and will eventually have a winner and is made up of multiple "*rounds.*"  Each *round* consists of all players flipping their coin and ends with looking at the results of those flips and determining whether or not there is a winner or if another round should occur.  Now, we could ask probability questions such as "What is the probability that player A wins the game" or we could ask "What is the probability that the game ends on the first round"

Comment: You could ask "what is the probability the game ends specifically on the $r$'th round?" or you could ask "what is the probability the game ends with player A as the winner on the $r$'th round" or "what is the probability the game ends *by the* $r$'th round" etc...  Some of those problems are certainly easier than others, but they should all follow easily from either binomial distribution, geometric distribution, or symmetry arguments.

Answer (score 0):

a coin is a "two sided die" so it either lands on 0 or 1. "if the result..." means one of two things: 1) all but one player rolls 0 OR 2) all but one player rolls 1

for n = 3, the following scenarios are possible for a single round (the * represents "any players toss is different from all the remaining" scenairo)

HHH, HHT*, HTH*, HTT*, THH*, THT*, TTH*, TTT

so out of the 8 possible scenarios, 6 of them end the game. That is, in any one round, there is a 6/8 = 75% chance of ending the game.  Since each round is independent, the chance of ending the game in exactly one round is 75%, in exactly two rounds is (1-.75)*.75 = .1875 (since there is a 25% probability the first game will continue), and so on. You can repeat this process until you get a general equation for n=3, and any r.

Now you can repeat this entire process for n = 4, 5, etc. Until you get a general equation for all n and r.

Comment: To end on the second game you must continue the first.

Comment: thanks @Karl, changed my answer

Answer (score 0):

Every round, there is a winner with probability $p$. There is a winner if and only if the set of results is
$$\{T,H,H,\cdots, H,H\} \quad \mbox{or} \quad \{H,T,T,\cdots, T,T\}$$
in any order.

For $n>2$, you should now be able to count how many possibilities this is to get $p = \frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$.

Now the game finishes in one round with probability $g_1 = p$. It finishes in two rounds with probability $(1-p) \times p$ -- one failure, and one success. You should be able to finish things from here.